# Why is HttpContext null in razor component?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, httpcontext, blazor-server-side

I'm using `HttpContext` from `IHttpContextAccessor` in a dotnet core 3.1 web app in a couple of scenarios. It is always set as I would expect.

However, `HttpContext` is always null when injecting `IHttpContextAccessor` into a razor component.

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

<div>...</div>

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // here, HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext == null
    }

    public string GetSomeInfo()
    {
        // here, HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext == null
    }
}
```

I have added `IHttpContextAccessor` in `Startup.cs/ConfigureServices()` like so

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Why is `HttpContext` `null` here?

Comment: In server side blazor you should use `AuthenticationStateProvider` instead of `HttpContext`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#authenticationstateprovider-service

Comment: Did you check the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/q/53817373/2224701 ?

Answer (score 2):

I usually add a parameter to razor component. Suppose you stored a string in HttpContext.State and want to display it in a razor component:

**Counter.razor:**

```
<span>Application Name: @AppTitle</span>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public HttpContext MyContext { get; set; }

    public string AppTitle => MyContext.State.GetString("APP_KEY");
}
```

The component in your razor page:

```
<component type="typeof(Counter)" render-mode="Static" param-MyContext="@HttpContext" />
```