# SignOut of Azure AD in Blazor Server-Side without WebAPI

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor-server-side

I have a Server-Side Blazor app that I am developing.  I have it linked up to Azure AD and authenticating.  This all works fine using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI`.  From what I can tell the SignOut feature is just a navigation path that leads to the AzureAD area in the WebAPI of the assembly.  Any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
            var domain = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.ToUriComponent();
            var redirectUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode($"{HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{domain}/Index");
    HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Redirect($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{domain}/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={redirectUrl}");
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it from inside a Blazor page?

Comment: Nevermind.  I figured it out.  ```protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var domain = Http.HttpContext.Request.Host.ToUriComponent();
        var redirect = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("<url>");
        Nav.NavigateTo($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{domain}/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={redirect}");
    }

Comment: Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53817373/how-do-i-access-httpcontext-in-server-side-blazor in order to access HttpContextAccessor from your server side blazer page. I've edited my answer accordingly.