# Blazor Server App - How to loop through request server variables

Tags: blazor, request.servervariables

In classic ASP, the way to loop through all request's server variables was like this:

```
for each x in Request.ServerVariables
   response.write(x & " = " & Request.ServerVariables(x) & "<br />")
next
```

To get an individual variable such as `http_user_agent` you would call

```
Request.ServerVariables("http_user_agent")
```

In ASP.NET, you run

```
 foreach (string s in Request.Params.Keys)
     s.ToString() + " - " + Request.Params[s];
```

Session variables are obtained like this:

```
 foreach (string s in Session.Keys)
            s.ToString() + " - " + Session[s];
```

How can I loop through server and session variables in a Blazor server app running on an IIS server?

Comment: See @Enet's answer to this question on how to access the httpcontext - See this answer on how to get access to the HttpContext - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53817373/how-do-i-access-httpcontext-in-server-side-blazor.  Remember this is a SPA so it only contains the information for the SPA initial page.

Comment: Thank you! Can you define SPA?

Comment: SPA: Single Page App... got it! :)